# Jquery Image Upload Count and Limit

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to come up with a possible solution for uploading images with an instant preview. This is all done via J'Query but I wish to throw an alert if the user try's uploading more than what is allowed.

The code that Uploads the images :

```
$(".share_button").click(function() 
        {
            var shareval = $("#share").val();
            var uploadvalues=$("#uploadvalues").val();
            var X = $('.preview').attr('id');

            if(X)
            {
                var Z = X+','+uploadvalues;
            }   
            else
            {
                var Z = 0;
                var dataString = 'share='+ shareval+'&uploads='+Z;
            }

            if($.trim(shareval).length==0)
            {
                alert("Please Enter Some Text");
            }
            else
            {
                // Hide No Shares If Visible
                $("#Nodata").slideUp();                    
                // Display Quick Update
                $("#flash").show();
                $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('Posting Share...');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>app/web/home/share_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {

                        $("#flash").fadeOut('slow');
                        $("#content").prepend(html);
                        $("#share").val('');   
                        $("#share").focus();
                        $('#preview').html('');
                        $('#uploadvalues').val('');
                        $('#photoimg').val('');
                    }
                });

                $("#preview").html('');
                $('#imageupload').slideUp('fast');
            }
            return false;
        });
```

I thought a solution could be placing this before the text check :

```
 if( $.trim(X).length > 2)
 {
   alert("Only Two Images No More");
 }
```

But this did not work, I'm not too hot with J'Query. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED:

This is the HTML markup:

```
    <div id="imageupload" style="display:none;">        
    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>app/web/home/image_ajax.php'> 
        <!-- Upload Preview -->
        <div id="preview"></div>
        <!-- Upload Image -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" style="display:none"/>
        <a id="upload-share-button" class="button" style="width:570px;text-align:center;margin:10px;">Upload Images</a>
        <input type='hidden' id='uploadvalues'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: _"if the user try's uploading more than what is allowed."_ Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that at the moment the user can upload as many as they desire. I would wish to place a limit, so they can only upload say 2 images..

Comment: Are using multiple attribute for file inputs?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing your HTML, could you post it?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is going to work as you have it.  You can't upload a file using ajax, if you want an ajax upload you need to use something like this - http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html.  Or has the image already been uploaded and you are just trying to share it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using multiple attribute for the file input, you can check the length of selected images/files using `length` property of the `files` object:

```
var len = $("#uploadvalues").get(0).files.length;
if (len > 2) {
   alert("Only Two Images No More");
   return;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xhk/

Note that Internet Explorer doesn't support File API.

Comment: Hi undefined, I tried your above code and this broke the j'Query I have updated my questin with the HTML markup.

Comment: @LeeMarshall Hi, I thought you are trying to count the length of files object, but you are not using multiple attribute, what are you trying to achieve?